# Create document and email as a PDF

Tags: email, pdf, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a Daily Overview document that I can read each morning by way of a PDF delivered to my email. I have a script that creates a Google Doc but whenever I try to email it as a PDF it sends a completely blank document. When I check the Google doc (which I am currently also emailing to help test for bugs) it shows what I want. This is what I am using to create the PDF:

```
var pdfDocument = DriveApp.getFileById(ID).getAs("application/pdf");
```

This part works when I replace 'ID' with a string ID copied from an already existing doc. The variable 'ID' is defined as:

```
var ID = doc.getId();
```

I know this is pulling the correct ID because I have the logger set to display it and it matches the resulting Google Doc. I am new to scripting so forgive any mistakes or poor etiquette. [Here is a link to the script.](https://script.google.com/d/17EwYre8cz50XOlo-gL6OMm6NSX3s0ssLAW_oVn_EjSdfMcV53HvxB1IE/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was a nimrod. I added `doc.saveAndClose();` at the end of everything to do with the Google Doc but before getting the document as a PDF. Hope this helps someone else!